# "While I'm here", but in writing

Tags: expressions, email, letter-writing

Sometimes, there are little things that we would like to write to somebody, but they seem too little to deserve an entire new email.

So we wait for a more important communication to "piggyback" it and add this little piece of additional information.

In speech, I would introduce the minor topic with "While I'm here". Is there an equivalent idiom for written communication? Or does "while I'm here" still work, even if my *literal* location hasn't changed?

Example:

`To: landlord`

> Good morning,
>
> The technician came and he said the repair will be £350. You might prefer to contact him directly for details.
>
> ***[While I'm here]***, I should mention that a couple of letters arrived  for you yesterday, but they are most likely spam.
>
> ...

Comment: Would "*by the way*" work for you?

Comment: @michael.hor257k I doubt so: the context is quite formal (I'm writing to an adjudicator adding some information about a complaint)

Comment: I don't think *by the way* is any less formal than *while I'm here*. For more formal expressions, see: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/60577/may-by-the-way-be-used-in-formal-professional-writing

Comment: 'While I'm at it'? https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/while-i-m-you-re-etc-at-it

Comment: "While I'm at it" seems to remove the "spatial" connotation from the expression, which is what I was looking for. However, in the link you provide, it's categorised as "*spoken*". *By the way*, I ended up using "*In addition*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're describing a postscript.

> Good morning,
>   The technician came and he said the repair will be £350. You might prefer to contact him directly for details.
>   
>   - Nicola Sap
>   P.S. I should mention that a couple of letters arrived for you yesterday, but they are most likely spam.

Comment: +1 I was just about to suggest this myself.

Comment: As obvious as it seems, it didn't occur to me right then! Thanks